# Symfony Application on AWS ECS with a data-only container - Is this the right direction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I have a dockerized Symfony2 Application consisting of four containers:

- php-fpm
- nginx
- mysql
- code (data container with a volume)

On my local machine this setup runs without problem with docker-compose:

```
    code:
      image: ebc9f7b635b3

    nginx:
      build: docker/nginx  
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      links:
        - php
      volumes_from:
        - code

    php:
      build: docker/php
      volumes_from:
        - code
      links:
        - mysql

    mysql:
      image: mysql
      ports:
        - "5000:3306"
      command: mysqld --sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xyz
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=xyz
        - MYSQL_USER=xyz
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xyz
```

I wanted to deploy my application on AWS ECS, therefore I prebuilt all the images and pushed them to the AWS Container Registry, created a new cluster with a new service and translated my local docker-compose.yml to a TaskDefinition. 
Since yesterday I tried to get it running, but after following the Official Dokumentation 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html 
and searching for hours I can't find a way to get it working.

Either the service get stucked in a PENDING state without bringing up a container (except for the mysql container) or if I attach a volume to the task definition the containers coming up but the data is not mapped.

Is it that I must reference the data only container in a special syntax in the volumesFrom section of the Task Definition?

Is there a solution for this by now other than using EFS?

Thanks!